# ISTIO: error: no objects passed to apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, istio

Following blog post [here](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/05/managing-microservices-with-istio-service-mesh.html) I am trying to deploy this sample service on my aws k8s through istio gives me "error: no objects passed to apply"

**Setup**

- aws k8s v1.7.x
- istio 0.4.0

**Config**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: productpage
 labels:
   app: productpage
spec:
 type: NodePort
 ports:
 - port: 9080
   name: http
 selector:
   app: productpage
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: productpage-v1
spec:
 replicas: 1
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: productpage
       track: stable
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: productpage
       image: istio/examples-bookinfo-productpage-v1
       imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
       ports:
       - containerPort: 9080
```

**Issue**

`kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f book-info-v1.yaml)`

`error: no objects passed to apply`

Answer (score 2):

It probably means that `istioctl kube-inject` produced empty output in the `istioctl kube-inject -f book-info-v1.yaml` part. Try to run `istioctl kube-inject -f book-info-v1.yaml` as a separate command and see if it produces any errors.

Comment: gives me this, 
`istioctl kube-inject -f book-info-v1.yaml`
`Segmentation fault`

Comment: OK, so the problem is with `istioctl`. On which OS do you run it? Also, can you run `kubectl config get-contexts` that `kubectl` is configured correctly and can find its configuration?

Comment: I am on debian jessie,  `kubernetes164.dev-chx.net  kubernetes164b.dev-chx.net   kubernetes164b.dev-chx.net`

Comment: OK, so what is the output of `kubectl config get-context`?

Comment: here is the o/p I get when I did "kubectl config get-contexts"

```CURRENT   NAME                              CLUSTER                           AUTHINFO                          NAMESPACE
*         kubernetes164b2.dev-chx.net   kubernetes164b2.dev-chx.net   kubernetes164b2.dev-chx.net```

Comment: The next commands to try:
`istioctl version`;

`istioctl kube-inject -f samples/sleep/sleep.yaml`

The `sleep.yaml` is here https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/sleep/sleep.yaml, it appears in the Istio release archive, see here https://github.com/istio/istio/releases.

Comment: hmm, I tried commands above. both gives me `Segmentation fault` does this mean my installation didn't go well?

Comment: Yes, something is probably wrong with your installation. I would try to run also `istioctl help`, to be sure. How did you install `istioctl`?

Comment: updated from 0.4.0 to 0.5.0 resolved, thank you @Vadim